# How to fix 'ModuleNotFoundError: 'kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg''

Tags: python, matplotlib, kivy

I am learning how to use matplotlib with kivy. When I run the code below, it breaks and throws 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg''.

Tried looking up possible issues, some of which advised reverting back to matplotlib 2.2.2. I tried this and it still does not work. Open to any advice.

```
#Importing Packages
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import TextBox

from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

#adding figure and ax box to the screen
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
#setting distance from bottom for flot
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)

#setting initial x limits and precision
x = np.arange(-5.0, 5.0, 0.001)

#setting initial function and plotting
y = x ** 2
initial_text = "x ** 2"
l, = plt.plot(x, y, linewidth=2)

#defining the function of updating text
def submit(text):
    ydata = eval(text)
    l.set_ydata(ydata)
    ax.set_ylim(np.min(ydata), np.max(ydata))
    plt.draw()

#setting dimensions and location of text box
axbox = plt.axes([0.25, 0.05, 0.5, 0.075])
text_box = TextBox(axbox, 'f(x) = ', initial=initial_text)
text_box.on_submit(submit)


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        box = BoxLayout()
        box.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf()))
        return box

MyApp().run()
```

The only issue here is the FigureCanvasKivyAgg() function, which cannot be imported.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your code runs fine under Python3, Kivy 1.11.0-dev, Matplotlib version 2.1.1, Kivy Garden Matplotlib, and Xubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver. I presumed that you have installed Kivy Garden Matplotlib (*garden install matplotlib*).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have all necessary libraries installed. The following example is for a complete install of both garden and matplotlib for Python2.7.

First install garden using:

```
sudo pip install kivy-garden
```

Garden will get installed at: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/garden

Next, install matplotlib using:

```
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```

Then add the backend for garden.matplotlib using:

```
sudo garden install matplotlib --kivy
```

Note: You need the "--kivy" in the line above, to install globally.